# How to use the MT:EntryBody tag with additional modifiers for removing content

Tags: html, movabletype

I'm trying to remove text (with a specific class) from MT:EntryBody. More specifically, I'm trying to remove headers from my summary pages.

On this page, http://www.taconic.com/taconic-insights/microbiome-and-germ-free/, in the middle of the first entry there is text that says "Defining Rodent Health Standards". This makes no sense in the summary (because I'm stripping HTML - obviously). SO I want to just remove this line from the summary. I tried using a tag as well as a CSS hidden class but I can't get this to work properly.

Thoughts?

Comment: Could you post an example of the actual raw entry body showing the text around and including the part you're trying to remove, and also the code you're currently using to output it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify, you want to remove this in the entry body?

```
<h3 class="hidden">Defining Rodent Health Standards</h3>
```

Then, *before* stripping HTML, you need to use a regexp to catch and remove those blocs. Then, you can remove HTML.

See https://movabletype.org/documentation/appendices/modifiers/regex-replace.html

Comment: right so that's what I had tried and its still not working. First of all, I've removed the class=hidden as this was just some testing.

And then here is the code that I have for the summary pages.

`regex_replace="/(.*)<h3>\((.*)\)</h3>(.*)/",""`

Comment: That regexp doesn't look right. Try this one: `<$mt:EntryBody regex_replace="/(<h3.*\/h3>)/",""$>`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing you could do is to replace:

```
<$mt:EntryBody$>
```

With:

```
<$mt:EntryBody replace="Defining Rodent Health Standards",""$>
```

Glad to answer also other questions that you might have!